# Replicate Windows 7 Snap behaviour in Vista/XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, aero-snap

Windows 7 has the new Snap feature: the process of pushing a window against the side of the screen (or using a new hotkey) to snap it onto part of the screen space (this also allows for easy side-by-side comparison if snapping two windows: one to the left side of the screen and the other to the right).

Can this snap effect be done in Vista/XP with a modification of some kind?

For reference, a video of the Windows 7 snap effects are seen here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzQQcdw1qmY&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this awhile back, its called [AeroSnap](http://www.aerosnap.de/eng/download.htm). A friend of mine had asked the same question. Hope it helps.

Website appears to be broken. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315060231/http://www.aerosnap.de/eng/download.htm) is a mirror.

Comment: Indeed that software implements the Windows 7 snap features on Windows XP/Vista. Works great. Thanks for the info!